# custom search sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-2007

anyone knows how I can create or customize a search in sharepoint, so I only look in certain lists and only find certain items that meet a condition of validity

Answer (score 0):

I need to know this too.  Does the properties need to be added into the Central Administration for the properties to be crawled?

http://www.alectang.com/Blog/Archive/2010/01/11/Customise-Advanced-Search-box-in-Sharepoint-55.aspx

I read this, but it doesn't make sense.